# jQueryUI - Datepicker help!

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

Okay, my problem's simple. The datepicker has lack of years in the year dropdown (from 2001 to 2021) I need the years to be from 1965 to 2000. How would I change the years dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [yearRange](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-yearRange), is accepts two parameters, a start and an end value.

```
.datepicker({yearRange:'1965:2000'});
```